# For a nondecreasing map, if $\xi(a) < \eta(a)$, then $\xi(t) < \eta(t)$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, monotone-functions

I am studying the following theorem from Morris Hirsch's second paper on systems of differential equations which are competitive or cooperative:

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be on open set and $G:\mathbb{R} \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuous map such that $G^i(t,x^1,\cdots,x^m)$ is a non decreasing in $x^k$, for all $k \neq i$. Let
$$\xi,\eta : [a,b] \rightarrow V $$
be solutions of 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}= G(t,x)$$
such that  $\xi(a) < \eta(a)$ (resp. $\xi(a) \leq \eta(a)$). Then $\xi(t) < \eta(t)$ ( resp. $\xi(t) \leq \eta(t)$) for all $t \in [a,b]$.

I would love to find a proof but cannot find one anywhere or figure it out. Can anyone suggest where to begin?

Comment: This is not a full solution, but a possible direction to look at. It's pretty easy to show that for any $k$ inequality $\frac{d}{dt}(\eta_k -\xi_k) > 0$ holds in a small neighbourhod of $t = a$ and thus solutions are still non-decreasing (or increasing). We can show that this property holds for an open subset of solution's interval of existence (which is open itself). Maybe it is possible to exclude the case that "non-decreasing interval" has an upper limit in the interior of solution's interval of existence.